# Displaying only Base URL in Angular 7

Tags: angular, angular-ui-router

I'm using Angular 7. My base URL is http://localhost:4200/ and when i clicked Search option from the menu the URL is changed to http://localhost:4200/search. is there a any way to display only base URL "http://localhost:4200/" whenever i click search link.

Comment: `search` refers to the `path` name basically your current `route`.

Comment: can yo u share your code here ?

Comment: {
    path: 'search', component: SearchComponent
  },

Answer (score 2):

You can use

```
this.router.navigateByUrl('path', { skipLocationChange: true });

router.navigate(['team', 33, 'user', 11], {relativeTo: route, skipLocationChange: true});
```

More information can be found from the following link

[Angular Router](https://angular.io/api/router/Router)